# What do the yellow boxes with a dot mean in War on the tank progress?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

In the game type War, some levels have you escorting tanks to a certain point on the map (depending which faction you are fighting for).  I've noticed that sometimes, the progress bars for the tanks contain a yellow box with a dot in it:

[image: boxes]

What do these boxes indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These yellow boxes indicate the point at which the tank will be stopped by a hedgehog built by the other team.  What is a [hedgehog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_hedgehog)? These are those "X" shaped metal barriers that the other team builds.  You can blow them up by placing an explosive charge on them.

[image: hedgehog]

The tanks will only be able to make there way to the edge of the yellow box which indicates that they have reached one of these hedgehogs.  Destroy the hedgehog, and the tank will be able to advance.

Comment: Small tip, if you shoot the C4 after you plant it, it will explode instantly saving you precious time to push your tank forward.

Comment: On the attacking side you can also build the hedgehogs behind the tanks so that they can't go too far backwards if the defending side pushes you off the tank.